# Переменную из PHP В Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

У меня есть переменная, которая содержится в сессии.     $_SESSION["secretnumber"]<br/>
Есть главный файл index.php<br/>
В нём мне надо эту переменную записать в переменную js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    a = <?php echo $_SESSION["secretnumber"] ?>
</script>
```

Однако так не прокатывает. Что можно ещё попробовать?

Comment: Этот вопрос будет вечен....

Comment: А что получается, когда исходный html-код страницы смотришь?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = <?php echo $_SESSION["secretnumber"]; ?>;
</script>
```

Может все дело в ; ? Все работает у меня.

Comment: Всё разобрался. Всем спасибо!

Comment: Интересно, почему не работало до этого, вроде всё нормально, точка с запятой ни там ни там не обязательна...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так( сделать это из PHP ):

```
<?php

$a = $_SESSION["secretnumber"] ;

echo ('
<script>
a = '.$a.'
</script>
');

?>
```

**Так точно но все должно получиться =)**

Comment: Unexpected end of input. Такая ошибка.

Comment: Ну дык поправьте) если знаете, что такое PHP.

Comment: @Dexter это не php виноват а вы я точно не помню но переводы срок воспринимаются как конец выражения и надо как то так: 

   echo "<<<text
       <script>
           a = $a;
       </script>
   <<<text";

Comment: я не php'шник поэтому не помню точно, но как то так: строки где вместо спецсимвола используется настоящий перевод строки надо ограничивать <<< метками и кстати echo это ОПЕРАТОР поэтому скобки не нужны и ещё, зачем выполнять конкатенацию строк в апострофах, когда в php вся фишка в инкапсуляции строк в кавычках

Comment: @Rules, не лезь туда, в чем не разбираешься( как сам утверждаешь )!

Comment: и вообще главная фишка PHP это встраивание в HTML код (как у @Святослав'a и @Владимир'а)? Ваш подход 
1) Жрёт память
2) При разных кодировках напечатает абракадабру

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">var sNumber='<?=$_SESSION["secretnumber"]?>';</script>
```

Вот так должно работать (работает на живом проекте). 
Если не работает:
 - проверь что лежит в $_SESSION["secretnumber"] на момент генерации страницы (сделай

```
<?=var_dump($_SESSION["secretnumber"]);?>
```

перед строкой яваскрипта.
 - открой исходный код страницы и посмотри полученное значение переменной sNumber (название ставь подходящее).

Дальше действуй по ситуации :) Не видя значений переменной получившейся или того, что находится в $_SESSION["secretnumber"] на момент генерации страницы - сложно подсказать что-то.